# Want to create transformation such that it picks output of other transformation as input

Tags: pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a problem statement where I have a data set which I m getting from the database, and the transformation does some modification on the values that we get from the table.

Eg -
| Id | Y |
| -- | - |
| 1  | 10|
|  2 | 10|
|  1 | 5 |
Now this is suppose the XML file and in database we have Id and it's corresponding quantity. The transformation should subtract Y from ID's quantity and give output of the result. For same Id the last updated amount for that particular id from the previous result should be considered as quantity, and Y should be subtracted for that.

I m new to pentaho so need ur advice on how to achive this. Would like detailed information. Thanks in advance.

We can go for two seperate transformation but the first transformation gives xmls for each id seperately as output and I don't know how to take it as a input for next transformation.

Answer (score 1):

You end your first transformation with the step "Copy rows to result" and then in the second transformation you have two options:

- Call the first transformation with a "Transformation executor" step and process the stream of rows.
- Create a second transformation with parameters to treat each row from the first transformation at a time, and run a job with the first transformation first and then the second transformation. In the job you configure the properties of the call to the second transformation with the check: "Execute every input row" and in the the Parameters tab you indicate the name of the column of the first transformation that goes to the parameters of the second.

Some quick examples of what you do in each of those cases:
[image: Using a Transformation Executor]
[image: Executing for each row in the job]